# How to declare a nested IList property on Realm object without getting "not supported" error?

Tags: list, xamarin, casting, realm, geojson

Basically I am trying to save a GeoJSON to my Realm DB of my Xamarin.Forms application and it has a property as provided below (nested list of double)

```
public class GeoJSONGeometry : RealmObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public IList<IList<IList<double>>> Coordinates { get; }
}
```

But trying to build the application results in below error:

Fody/Realm: GeoJSONGeometry.Coordinates is an IList but its generic type is IList`1 which is not supported by Realm.

Please suggest how this can be dealt with.

Update:
I used the below code to replace the original one and the error disappeared. Please suggest if there is any alternative

```
public class DoubleList : RealmObject
{
    public IList<double> Coordinates { get; }
}

public class ListOfDoubleList : RealmObject
{
    public IList<DoubleList> CoordinatesList { get; }
}

public class GeoJSONGeometry : RealmObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public IList<ListOfDoubleList> CoordinatesListGroup { get; }
   
}
```

Comment: Can you share your geoJson example payload object (json).

Comment: @Anurag Please find the sample provided below:

[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Republican"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22,  48.98],
            [-96.58,  45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}]

Comment: Have you tried using string (while saving realm) instead of nested list and parse while you using on UI.

Comment: @Anurag No I haven't tried that yet. I will give it a try as well. Alternatively, is there any way to save the array as it is (in JSON format) in the realm?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, the main thing that I would suggest is using `EmbeddedObject` rather than `RealmObject` for the base class of these intermediate objects:

```
public class DoubleList : EmbeddedObject
{
    public IList<double> Coordinates { get; }
}

public class ListOfDoubleList : EmbeddedObject
{
    public IList<DoubleList> CoordinatesList { get; }
}

public class GeoJSONGeometry : RealmObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public IList<ListOfDoubleList> CoordinatesListGroup { get; }
   
}
```

This has the effect of introducing ownership semantics from `GeoJSONGeometry` all the way down to `DoubleList`, meaning that if you remove a geometry object from the Realm, it will also delete all `ListOfDoubleList` objects contained in the `CoordinatesListGroup` property, which will in turn delete all `DoubleList` objects that were contained in `ListOfDoubleList.CoordinatesList`.